# How to get the flask-python app to redirect to https with heroku without too many redirects error?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, heroku-cli

My website here: https://climatebin.herokuapp.com/ is showing this error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` I tried deleting cookies and going to Firefox, but none worked. I tried changing the https to http in the URL but it keeps redirecting to https. I don't have a SSL certificate and I'm using free dynos on Heroku. How do I get this to work?

This is my HTTP to HTTPS redirection code.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():

    # this checks if the user requests http and if they did it changes it to https
    if request.headers.get('X-Forwarded-Proto') == 'http':
        url = request.url.replace('http://', 'https://', 1)
        print("redirected to https?")
        code = 301
        return redirect(url, code=code)
```

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow community. You should point exactly where this error is coming from. I visited your website but can't figure out where this error is happening. Also the unique error I could see in console is: `Mixed Content` in browser console.

Comment: Apologies, it's the Google OAuth or when you log in. Try logging into the site. I can post the HerokuApp logs here if needed.

Comment: This is the [error](https://i.imgur.com/6oSpLJp.png).

Comment: It is a loop, because you are making a redirect to an address without https. Try to change the link to a https address for your application.

Comment: Added an edit to show my redirection code. And it didn't run my print code

Comment: You should configure the return callback from your oauth with google to be the https address. But not sure how to do that, never did with python.

Comment: If you click button login in your site, you will be redirected to an account google address, in the navigation bar from browser there is an uri, the `&redirect_uri=` must be an https address, yours contain a `http` address. This configuration should is made in google accounts.

Comment: do i need to update my credentials.json file too along with google cloud console

Comment: This makes another error that when i click login; it's a HTTP request now after doing what u said. edit: u should also see it

Comment: ```if not request.url.startswith('https'):
        return redirect(request.url.replace('http', 'https', 1))``` Does this work for HTTPS redirection? I currently testing this in before_request

Comment: Didn't worked. I removed the https redirection. I'm back where I started; u can check the website again. If I change the redirect uri to https it gives an authorization error 400 that it doesn't match with redirect_uri

Comment: This is what I get currently:

`Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, http://climatebin.herokuapp.com/oauth2callback, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/15282057415-ms3qa97o5b92j010up3l322rnc9vfa2q.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=15282057415`

Comment: As you can see the link is http. I need it to redirect to https because Oauth requires that.

Comment: In the error 400 showing currently there is an url to update the address to update the redirect URI.

Comment: Yes but i dont want it to go thru http traffic. the people api requires https traffic

Comment: Any idea? @Danizavtz

Comment: Https is a security concern, if you do not want do use it, I would recommend you drop the oauth authentication and use yours only. I think the too many redirects is happening because your are redirecting to a http address. If you redirect to a https, the error should not happen anymore.

Comment: I think i'm just over-optimistic. Heroku allows free ssl static hosting but not dynamic hosting. It's all good.

Answer (score 0):

My website is dynamic and relied on free Heroku dynos and SSL to run it. Heroku only runs free SSL for static websites.